# ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>) (line: 22342, col: 24, pos: 826182)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, reactjs, heroku

Fairly new rails developer here. I am running into this error message while trying to effectively deploy my rails app on Heroku. My guess is that some syntactical error is being run into when the JS assets precompile.

I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417990/precompiling-assets-failed-execjsprogramerror-unexpected-token-operator) on SO, but it seems that it is still unresolved and I have attempted all of the suggestions in the responses.

Any help is appreciated. Here's the command line trace of my issue:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>) (line: 22342, col: 24, pos: 826182)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20161001-3-1oidjycjs:3623:11948)
    at js_error (/tmp/execjs20161001-3-1oidjycjs:3623:12167)
    at croak (/tmp/execjs20161001-3-1oidjycjs:3623:22038)
    at token_error (/tmp/execjs20161001-3-1oidjycjs:3623:22175)
    at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20161001-3-1oidjycjs:3623:22263)
    at expr_atom (/tmp/execjs20161001-3-1oidjycjs:3623:31244)
    at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20161001-3-1oidjycjs:3624:1752)
    at expr_ops (/tmp/execjs20161001-3-1oidjycjs:3624:2523)
    at maybe_conditional (/tmp/execjs20161001-3-1oidjycjs:3624:2615)
    at maybe_assign (/tmp/execjs20161001-3-1oidjycjs:3624:3058)
    at maybe_assign (/tmp/execjs20161001-3-1oidjycjs:3624:3232)
    at expression (/tmp/execjs20161001-3-1oidjycjs:3624:3384)
    at expr_list (/tmp/execjs20161001-3-1oidjycjs:3623:31548)
    at subscripts (/tmp/execjs20161001-3-1oidjycjs:3624:1461)
new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):3623:11948)
js_error ((execjs):3623:12167)
croak ((execjs):3623:22038)
token_error ((execjs):3623:22175)
unexpected ((execjs):3623:22263)
expr_atom ((execjs):3623:31244)
maybe_unary ((execjs):3624:1752)
expr_ops ((execjs):3624:2523)
maybe_conditional ((execjs):3624:2615)
maybe_assign ((execjs):3624:3058)
maybe_assign ((execjs):3624:3232)
expression ((execjs):3624:3384)
expr_list ((execjs):3623:31548)
subscripts ((execjs):3624:1461)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.2/lib/uglifier.rb:181:in `run_uglifyjs'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.2/lib/uglifier.rb:143:in `compile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:52:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in `map'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in `precompiled_assets'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:35:in `asset_precompiled?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:251:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:359:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:359:in `precompiled?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:363:in `raise_unless_precompiled_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:337:in `digest_path'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:325:in `asset_path'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:102:in `block in resolve_asset_path'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `block in resolve_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `detect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `resolve_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:101:in `resolve_asset_path'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:79:in `compute_asset_path'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-5.0.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:144:in `asset_path'
/app/app/models/group.rb:11:in `<class:Group>'
/app/app/models/group.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `block in require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:117:in `exclusive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:511:in `load_missing_constant'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
/app/db/seeds.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:549:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:268:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:196:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: you can get this kind of exec js error when your coffeescript is invalid, are you sure it is working in development?

Comment: thanks for responding– i'm not running coffeescript. I just have some jquery and react components. Definitely runs ok locally. I only have issues when trying to seed in heroku, which I believe is running in the production env?

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem and as mentioned its because my version of Rails did not support ES6. Upgrading sprockets din work for me though. What I ended up doing was upgrading `uglifier` and in my `production.rb`, changing,

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

to

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

And then my precompile worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, and it turned out I was using an ES6 arrow function. The problem was, the version of Sprockets my production environment was using was not compatible with ES6 yet.

My solution at the time was to remove the arrow function. The alternative is to use something like [sprockets-es6](https://github.com/TannerRogalsky/sprockets-es6) or one of the beta version of [sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets).

Comment: I was using ES6 syntax in my Rails 4 project as well. I tried sprockets-es6, but that didn't help. As advised in this answer, I had to update my Gemfile and re-generate my Gemfile.lock to use a beta version of sprockets: gem 'sprockets', '~> 4.0.0.beta4'