# ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (<)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, coffeescript

I'm making my way through CareerFoundry's Web Development course and I've run into an issue getting a "precompiled assets failed" message. This is the original error message from just trying to upload my files to heroku

```
    ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (<) (line: 12192, col: 0, pos: 370557)
    remote:        Error
    remote:        at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20170412-395-1h7cphhjs:3623:11948)
    remote:        at js_error (/tmp/execjs20170412-395-1h7cphhjs:3623:12167)
    remote:        at croak (/tmp/execjs20170412-395-1h7cphhjs:3623:22038)
    remote:        at token_error (/tmp/execjs20170412-395-1h7cphhjs:3623:22175)
    remote:        at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20170412-395-1h7cphhjs:3623:22263)
    remote:        at expr_atom (/tmp/execjs20170412-395-1h7cphhjs:3623:31244)
    remote:        at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20170412-395-1h7cphhjs:3624:1752)
    remote:        at expr_ops (/tmp/execjs20170412-395-1h7cphhjs:3624:2523)
    remote:        at maybe_conditional (/tmp/execjs20170412-395-1h7cphhjs:3624:2615)
    remote:        at maybe_assign (/tmp/execjs20170412-395-1h7cphhjs:3624:3058)
    remote:        at expression (/tmp/execjs20170412-395-1h7cphhjs:3624:3384)
    remote:        at simple_statement (/tmp/execjs20170412-395-1h7cphhjs:3623:25942)
    remote:        new JS_Parse_Error ((

execjs):3623:11948)
remote:        js_error ((execjs):3623:12167)
remote:        croak ((execjs):3623:22038)
remote:        token_error ((execjs):3623:22175)
remote:        unexpected ((execjs):3623:22263)
remote:        expr_atom ((execjs):3623:31244)
remote:        maybe_unary ((execjs):3624:1752)
remote:        expr_ops ((execjs):3624:2523)
remote:        maybe_conditional ((execjs):3624:2615)
remote:        maybe_assign ((execjs):3624:3058)
remote:        expression ((execjs):3624:3384)
remote:        simple_statement ((execjs):3623:25942)
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:184:in `run_uglifyjs'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:146:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:53:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_83e6f5fa137e00570c8f3c555e0c4b73/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to sonntag-nacht.
```

I went through the steps detailed in the answer to [THIS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417990/precompiling-assets-failed-execjsprogramerror-unexpected-token-operator) and ran

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

which gave me this as a result:

```
    GabrielsMacBook:TestApp gabriellagricius$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:138: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (<) (line: 12192, col: 0, pos: 370557)

JS_Parse_Error@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3623:11957
js_error@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3623:12185
croak@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3623:22046
token_error@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3623:22180
unexpected@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3623:22274
expr_atom@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3623:31254
maybe_unary@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3624:1761
expr_ops@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3624:2534
maybe_conditional@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3624:2623
maybe_assign@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3624:3075
expression@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3624:3396
simple_statement@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3623:25952
/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3623:23678
/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3623:22960
/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3624:3768
parse@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3624:3999
parse@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:3958:27
uglifier@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:4003:18
eval code
eval@[native code]
/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:4039:12
/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:4043:21
/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:1:46
global code@/var/folders/jt/g3npcq397gzgmzvm4jqtcs8h0000gn/T/execjs20170412-73446-1lvsnmujs:1:58
JS_Parse_Error@(execjs):3623:11957
js_error@(execjs):3623:12185
croak@(execjs):3623:22046
token_error@(execjs):3623:22180
unexpected@(execjs):3623:22274
expr_atom@(execjs):3623:31254
maybe_unary@(execjs):3624:1761
expr_ops@(execjs):3624:2534
maybe_conditional@(execjs):3624:2623
maybe_assign@(execjs):3624:3075
expression@(execjs):3624:3396
simple_statement@(execjs):3623:25952
(execjs):3623:23678
(execjs):3623:22960
(execjs):3624:3768
parse@(execjs):3624:3999
parse@(execjs):3958:27
uglifier@(execjs):4003:18
(execjs):4039:12
(execjs):4043:21
(execjs):1:46
global code@(execjs):1:58
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:184:in `run_uglifyjs'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:146:in `compile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:53:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So I went back and looked at other solutions using the answer to [THIS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810489/execjsruntimeerror-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-operator-line-22342), which basically told me it was an ES6 error issue that wasn't compatible with coffeescript, so I added a gem to my gemfile from the latest version of sprockets to solve the problem but it didn't work... I've run bundle install and restarted my app to see if anything would help and so far I'm at a loss. I've just started with Ruby and I'm not really sure what to do now.

To give you an idea of what I was doing, I was trying to add the elevateZoom jquery with the normal file which is what started all of this (jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js) from their github repository.

If you want to look at my github code, it's all here. I'd super super appreciate anyone's help!
https://github.com/ggricius/TestApp

Comment: You have a syntax error in coffeescript

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari I haven't changed my coffeescript at all though, minus updating my site.js file and adding in the unedited version of the elevate jquery file?

Answer (score 2):

So I have fixed my own problem (as things usually go) and I wanted to post it so that other people could also learn from my mistakes. The issue with my code was in the elevateZoom file that I got from github. I didn't look at that code to see how different it looked because I just assumed it would be correct - and once I went to examine it, it turned out it was entirely the wrong file - so just a reminder to people to triplecheck files and not take their correctness for granted!