# ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token punc «(», expected punc «:» when running rake assets:precompile on production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, execjs

When deploying my Rails app I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
   ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token punc «(», expected punc «:» (line: 15, col: 14, pos: 265)

   Error
   at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20150524-4411-1p45n63js:2359:10623)
   at js_error (/tmp/execjs20150524-4411-1p45n63js:2359:10842)
   at croak (/tmp/execjs20150524-4411-1p45n63js:2359:19086)
   at token_error (/tmp/execjs20150524-4411-1p45n63js:2359:19223)
   at expect_token (/tmp/execjs20150524-4411-1p45n63js:2359:19446)
   at expect (/tmp/execjs20150524-4411-1p45n63js:2359:19584)
   at /tmp/execjs20150524-4411-1p45n63js:2359:28513
   at /tmp/execjs20150524-4411-1p45n63js:2359:19957
   at expr_atom (/tmp/execjs20150524-4411-1p45n63js:2359:27269)
   at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20150524-4411-1p45n63js:2359:30019)new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):2359:10623)
   js_error ((execjs):2359:10842)
   croak ((execjs):2359:19086)
   token_error ((execjs):2359:19223)
   expect_token ((execjs):2359:19446)
   expect ((execjs):2359:19584)
   (execjs):2359:28513
   (execjs):2359:19957
   expr_atom ((execjs):2359:27269)
   maybe_unary ((execjs):2359:30019)
```

The file in question is valid, it works on localhost. I also tried running `rake assests:precompile` on localhost, it all passes. Finally, I tried to remove the content from the file, git push and redeploy - still got the same error. Only completely removing the file and re-deploying helps.

Would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Are you talking about manifest file? pls explain it clearly

Comment: No, it's not a manifest file. It's a .js file that is included into application.js with the //= require directive.

Comment: Which CSS code cause this problem? Can you provide it? Which version of execjs are you using?

Comment: It's not CSS code, it's Javascript. Unfortunately I can't provide it, but it is valid and compiles just fine with `rake asset:precompile" on localhost. Not sure how to check ExecJS version, my Gemfile.lock has execjs, but lists no version.

Comment: Apologies, execjs version in my Gemfile.lock is 2.5.2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574977/rake-assetsprecompile-gives-punc-error?rq=1 Check here

Comment: Nope, this doesn't help. I've seen this post. My Javascript is fine, no errors and works perfectly fine on localhost.

Comment: **Was this ever resolved?** I seem to be having the same problem.
Info: sprockets (2.12.3), uglifier (2.2.1), execjs (2.5.2), sprockets-rails (2.3.1)

Comment: I just removed the `uglifier` gem temporarily, but no, it was never resolved.

Comment: Exact same error here and removing the `uglifier` gem does allow it compile assets on heroku.

Comment: Inspired by your comments, I have just posted an answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/32280270/226255

Comment: Can someone explain how you know what file the error is referring to? Based on this error, how can I determine which is the actual JS file causing the error?

Comment: @snitko it would be great for everyone if you select the correct answer, it seems that Rasovan Skendzic 's answer is the best!

Answer (score 262):

[Here I found help for the same problem you had.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38228770/4386214)

Run rails console and:

```
JS_PATH = "app/assets/javascripts/**/*.js"; 
Dir[JS_PATH].each do |file_name|
  puts "\n#{file_name}"
  puts Uglifier.compile(File.read(file_name), harmony: true)
end
```

It will show you the file and the line where the Uglifier is making the problem.

Comment: Why not just `uglify().on("error", function(error){console.log(error);})`? This will give you all you need...

Comment: This is the correct answer. It will find any errors you have regardless if they are the similar to the one above or not.

Comment: @Cipi where can i run that?

Comment: works! although I just needed to do: `require 'uglifier'` before that

Comment: Just to add support for erb files with a "*" at the end of dir mask, this may save time to someone: `"app/assets/javascripts/**/*.js*" <-- * at the end

Comment: Hi @cipi. I'm not sure where to add `uglify().on("error", function(error){console.log(error);})`. Can you add more context please?

Comment: @Jaswinder I'm sorry you didn't manage to solve your problem with this solution.

Comment: @RadovanSkendzic Sorry But your solution help me in a different way.Nice solution

Comment: I've came back to this multiple times now and it was a huge help. In this case, I got used to writing ES6 and Typescript syntax and some methods were short-hand and using string templates. Isolating it down to the troubled file is a major win.

Comment: This works great! I had to do a slight syntax change.                       
JS_PATH = "app/assets/javascripts/**/*.js"; Dir[JS_PATH].each do |file_name| puts "\n#{file_name}"; puts Uglifier.compile(File.read(file_name)) end

Comment: for me the error appeared only on precompiled assets on development  where no uglifying id done. so for me run that over: `JS_PATH = "public/assets/**/*.js";

Comment: You can easily turn this into a rake task, for example `rake javascript:test_compilation`

Comment: In my case, it wasn't a specific line that was throwing an error, but the fact that I was using ES6 syntax that was blowing everything up.  It may be worth mentioning the need to update uglifier if it doesn't actually give you a specific line as a problem.  Once I updated the uglifier, it gave me a useful error about needing to use harmony: true to proceed.

Comment: For anyone unable to identify the EXACT line causing the issue in the file(s) shown via Radovan's solution, try https://www.jslint.com/ and https://eslint.org/demo/. I first cleaned up my code using the former, and finally identified the issue causing `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` to break via the latter.

Comment: @RonLugge Thank you very much! updating uglifier fix my problem too!

Comment: Isn't working for me as it returns "(Unexpected token: operator (<))" on my js.erb files because of the mixed ruby code.

Comment: Updating Uglifier and precompiling my assets did, however, point out the issue.

Answer (score 33):

I suspect, in that js file, you have something like the following:

```
var User = {
    getName() {
        alert("my name");
    }
}
```

Replacing it with the right format,

```
var User = {
    getName: function() {
        alert("my name");
    }
}
```

worked for me.

Error is clearly saying, it's expecting ":" but it found "(".

Comment: This was the issue for me. As well as having arrays that use a variable the same name as a key: *Don't use* `{ id, content }` *Do use* `{ id: id, content: content }`

Comment: My issue was default params in a function: `function test(param1='val1', param2='val1') {}`. Apparently that only became a thing in ES2015.

Comment: This error is shockingly common when you are context-switching between ES6 and old-school JavaScript!

Answer (score 7):

Just encounter the same issue.

My case is someone used syntax that's only support since ES2015, ex

```
function someThing(param = true) {
    // do something here
};
```

while this is not supported in our environment.

And the error messages is actually generated by Uglifer.

Comment: yes, that fix when I got error on gulp --production

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure of your build chain, but I got here by pasting the same error message into Google.

That is called 'shorthand properties' in ES2015. I'm using Babel 6 with Gulp and needed to do an `npm install babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties --save-dev` and add that transform to my babel plugins.

```
.pipe(babel({
    plugins: [
        'transform-es2015-shorthand-properties'
    ]
}))
```

https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties

Comment: where to add this?

Answer (score 6):

I could use https://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/ to identify the correct line number where the issue was. Thankfully, at least the correct file which had an issue was pointed out by grunt uglify

Comment: This actually works great for me, it tells me exactly which line has the error. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If Radovan's answer isn't working for you due to a problem in a library instead of your code, you can try upgrading Uglifier and enabling ES6 compilation.

**Gemfile.lock**

```rb
gem 'uglifier', '~> 4.1'
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```rb
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

Answer (score 5):

December/2019 answer: starting on version 4.2.0 (released in Sept/2019), Uglifier now shows a beautiful (colored!) debug output showing you the offending line of code.

I was having a `Uglifier::Error: Unexpected character '`'` error and I couldn't find it even following all the other solutions in this page.

So go to your Gemfile, and set your Uglifier to be at least 4.2:

```
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 4.2'
```

Run `bundle update uglifier` to update it.

And then just look at the output, it will show you something like this:

[image]

Comment: This should probably be the top result nowadays. Doesn't seem to be any compatibility issues to updating uglifier either.

Answer (score 3):

In my case problem with function definition like,

```
function someFunctionName(param1, param2=defaultValue){
  //code 
}
```

Due to above function definition I was getting error, as it is not supported by Uglifier. Default parameters is ES6/ES2015 language specification.

For solution to above problem you can refer [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 1):

As the backtrace doesn't provide information about the corrupted file, for me the best way to identify the error is use [git bisect.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect)

It allows you to find the commit that introduces a bug.

Let's suppose you are on master, first you start git bisect:

```
$ git bisect start
$ git bisect bad
```

Then you go back to a previous, working revision, let's suppose 20 revision ago.

```
$ git checkout HEAD~20
```

You run the same command

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

If it works you mark revision as good:

```
$ git bisect good.
```

git will jump to another revision, you run same command again (assets:precompile) and bassed on the output mark it as good / bad.

In less than 1 minute you should be able to find what's the commit that introduced the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Update **uglifier** gem to last version and update your production.rb

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are maintaining a legacy project(with ruby very old version e.g. 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.x), I suggest you don't use uglifier&exec-js, simply comment out this line of code from `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.compress = true
```

also make sure you installed `nodejs` as the js run time.

refer to: ["rake assets:precompile" gives punc error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574977/rake-assetsprecompile-gives-punc-error)