# Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token punc «;», expected punc «,»

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When deploying my Rails app on heroku I get the following error,

```
    remote:        Bundle completed (163.81s)
    remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
    remote: -----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
    remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
    remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
    remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
    remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
    remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
    remote:        rake aborted!
    remote:        Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token punc «;», expected punc «,»
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:234:in `parse_result'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:216:in `run_uglifyjs'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:168:in `compile'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/compressing.rb:65:in `block in js_compressor='
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy_proc_processor.rb:31:in `call'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `blockin load'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
    remote:        /tmp/build_eb48b48285b82dae89f9dfd764c51c22/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `'
    remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
    remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    remote:
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote: Verifying deploy...
```

I've already modify the line in `production.rb` to,

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

but error persists.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422437/execjsprogramerror-unexpected-token-punc-expected-punc-when-running/38605526#38605526

Comment: the return of that command was:


Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token eof «undefined», expected punc «,». To use ES6 syntax, harmony mode must be enabled with Uglifier.new(:harmony => true).
 from (irb):18:in `block in irb_binding'
 from (irb):16:in `each'
 from (irb):16

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem arises because your version of Sprockets or Rails can't play nicely with the newer Uglifier. At least in Rails 3.2.22, `.map` files get generated and then treated as whatever the next suffix up is. E.g. Sprockets tries to compress `application.js.map` as if it were a js file.

One solution is to tell Sprockets to ignore map files by adding a line to your `config/environments/production.rb` file (or whatever config file you please):

```rb
config.assets.precompile[0] =  Proc.new { |path| !File.extname(path).in?(['.js', '.css', '.map']) }
```

Before you copy-paste the code above, you should verify that you're replacing the right item(s) in the pre-existing `config.assets.precompile` array. This array holds procs which determine which files get processed. For me, there were two items in the array, and the first one was as follows:

```rb
#<Proc:0x0055819620f6f8@/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:48>
```

Looking at the indicated location (`gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:48`) for the definition of the foregoing proc reveals:

```rb
Proc.new{ |path| !File.extname(path).in?(['.js', '.css']) }
```

...which selects every non-js, non-css file. Adding `'.map'` to that list of exclusions would prevent the `.map` files from being fed through the compressor.