# ExecJS::ProgramError in Home#index in Production mode, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 5 app, Screen shot below:
[image]

Please help.

Nodejs is installed completely and works in development mode.

Comment: You're probably missing a semi-colon in one of your *.js files. Can you check them and let me know if that's the case?

Comment: Works well in development mode.

Comment: Didn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574977/rake-assetsprecompile-gives-punc-error) help?

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help

Comment: can you try once changing double quotes to single around "home-bg.jpg"

Comment: @PradeepSapkota, Check the last answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422437/execjsprogramerror-unexpected-token-punc-expected-punc-when-running) question. You can find the exact line where the error occurs. Looks like you're missing a comma.

Comment: The problem was that there I left some brackets open in code. And I added to gems. I fixed the code there was still problem. When I removed those gems. It works fine. Thanks @ArunKumar and all.

Comment: @PradeepSapkota Answer your own question. Might be helpful for someone in the future :)

Comment: I think your first comment is answer.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38228770/3161291